# Storage area of public variables in a freeRTOS environment

Tags: c, memory-management, global-variables, freertos

Where do the global public variables (not declared inside a task body) get stored in a FreeRTOS environment?

What memory size configuration in the system will ensure that they get enough (non-overlapping) space for storage like either:

1. `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` defined in FreeRTOSConfig.h, or
2. these parameters defined in the linker script: 
   `_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;   /* required amount of heap  */
   _Min_Stack_Size = 0x400;  /* required amount of stack */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in the global memory, but not "on the heap" in the sense that the C compiler won't generate calls to the FreeRTOS `heap_x.c` (where `x` is one of the heap implementation numbers) to allocate this memory, it will simply stuff it into the correct section, and the linker will position that section somewhere in memory.

The memory that is used as the heap's backing store will generally also be of the same form, i.e. we have this in `heap_2.c`:

```
static uint8_t ucHeap[ configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE ];
```

that is simply declaring a global variable that is an array of the specified size; this will then be located in actual memory by the linker as would any other variable.

This is assuming a flash-based platform, i.e. not one where the FreeRTOS program is *dynamically* loaded at run-time by some code, in that case of course that code must fit all the sections of the program into memory and might indeed allocate heap memory to do so.

Comment: the reason why I asked this question was, actually I have 6 big structures defined in the global space. At specific size, they work fine, but when I uniformly increase their size to some bigger value, I don't see any hard fault or any stack overflow in the system but I see the data in these arrays is getting corrupted. Any idea what could be the issue, do I need to increase the _Min_Stack_Size or something?

Comment: Sounds a lot like a stack overflow, yes. The usual hints are: use debugger watchpoints to watch the arrays; enable FreeRTOS stack monitoring; try disabling tasks one at a time to see if the error goes away.

Comment: I have 3 tasks, each task uses 2 of those arrays. When I disabled the other 2 tasks, I witness there happens no more corruption. But I am curious why FreeRTOS did not report a stack overflow when all tasks are enabled and I see data corruption?

Answer (score 2):

FreeRTOS is supplied as C source code that is compiled as part of your project along with your other C source code - so unless you are specifically using a customer linker script (as would be the case if you were using a version of FreeRTOS that supports memory protection) then the answer to the original question is - where everything is stored is exactly the same as if FreeRTOS were not used as your compiler just sees C code.  So just like in any other standard C program you can increase the size of your structures until they are too large to fit on the MCU you are using - you will know when that is because [assuming your linker script is correct] the application will no longer link.  If you are seeing these structures get corrupted then it is for another reason, like stack overflow, not because they are stored in the wrong place.  Some links that might help:
https://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#configASSERT
https://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html